# User stuck in loading Webview. Where to set timeout, and how to allow user to navigate out of webview?

Tags: android

I have a Webview which during slow network connections takes a long time to load.  The problem beyond that is that the user is essentially stuck on the Webview. Clicking on the back button does NOT close out the Webview activity, at least not on 2.2 devices.  What can I do to allow users to navigate back from the Webview if its taking too long?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might need to `dismiss the progress dialog` and even you can destroy( by setting `finish()` ) the present webview activity by setting the **timer**. You can set whatever time you need. For example, if it takes more than 5 minutes, then you can set the time limit to 5 minutes and dismiss the dialog and destroy the activity. You can also follow as in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453034/android-how-to-set-time-for-progressdialog), if you want . Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: I dont know whether it solves the issue or not, as the **OP is not respponding.:p**. but it deserves +1