# How can I close a ProgressDialog after a set time?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-dialog

I am trying to close a ProgressDialog box automatically after 3 seconds. Here is the dialog:

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setTitle("Connecting");
progress.setMessage("Please wait while we connect to devices...");
progress.show();
```

I have tried a few methods, but I am unable to get any one of them to work. A simple time or anything would hopefully suffice. Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

AsyncTask is okay if you are processing a long running task and then want to cancel it after, but it's a bit overkill for a 3 second wait.  Try a simple handler.

```
    final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress.setTitle("Connecting");
    progress.setMessage("Please wait while we connect to devices...");
    progress.show();

    Runnable progressRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            progress.cancel();
        }
    };

    Handler pdCanceller = new Handler();
    pdCanceller.postDelayed(progressRunnable, 3000);
```

Updated adding show/hide:

```
progress.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        theLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Comment: In doing this, would it be possible to easily add in hide/show relative layouts after the 3000 timer?

Comment: Yes, you can either add it in the Runnable run() method, but then you'd have to add a runOnUIThread call.  Its easier to add a progress onCancelListener(), I've updated the code above.

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you. I have so many more question but I know this isn't the forum. Thanks again good sir!